# Afinando uma busca com o Analytics API + PHP

Tags: google-analytics-api

Alguém poderia me ajudar a montar uma busca? no API do google?

1) O original e que funciona, e me devolve quantas sessões foram feitas naquele período, é a mesma do exemplo do google:

```
function getResultsA(&$analytics, $profileId) {<br>
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions<br>
  // for the last seven days.<br>
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(<br>
       'ga:' . $profileId,<br>
       '7daysAgo',<br>
       'today',<br>
       'ga:sessions');<br>
}
```

2) Eu preciso pegar  as **"KEY WORDS" (ga:keyword)** como no exemplo que funciona pelo painel do analitics...

[como nesse exemplo](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A104341295&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3Akeyword&sort=-ga%3Asessions&access_token=ya29.4QFtGVKTAiwUOZ9YmJuWo1eK9gt5MRvik6VGk5Z2OR0gnaFNb-oeP6OweFropFYfhMoR7A)

ou seja, nesse exemplo eu tenho uma "metric" + "dimension" que funcionam!!
e me trazem todas as keywords!!

3)  LOGO A PERGUNTA, como ficaria a mesma busca no gapi + php? assim?

```
function getResultsA(&$analytics, $profileId) {<br>
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions<br>
  // for the last seven days.<br>
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(<br>
       'ga:' . $profileId,<br>
       '7daysAgo',<br>
       'today',<br>
       //'ga:sessions');<br>
       'ga:sessions, ga:keyword, -ga:sessions');<br>
}
```

Sendo que só estou conseguindo mensagem de erro falando que a "métrica é desconhecida"

Fiz varias combinações sem sucesso e não achei um exemplo de como "escrever" essa busca.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getResultsA(&$analytics, $profileId) {

        $metricas = 'ga:sessions,ga:transactions,ga:transactionsPerSession,ga:transactionRevenue';
        $dimensions = 'ga:campaign,ga:source,ga:adContent,ga:medium,ga:keyword';

        return $analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:' . $profileId,
            '7daysAgo',
            'today',
            $metricas,
            array('dimensions' => $dimensions)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar uma explicação junto sua resposta? É sempre bom ter uma explicação sobre as modificação para que todos possam entender melhor o que está sendo feito

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem "*Métrica desconhecida*" é exibida pois `ga:keyword` é uma `dimension`, não uma `metric`. Tente a consulta da seguinte maneira:

```
$analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:xxxxxx',
            '7daysAgo',
            'today',
            ['ga:sessions'],
            ['ga:keyword']
);
```